# jquery radio button change event is not fired if radios are hidden

Tags: jquery, event-handling, radio-button

I´m using this code on hidden radio buttons:

```
        $('input:radio[name="test"]').change(function(){
            console.log("test");
        });
```

The change event is not fired.

PS: the radios are invisible cause I have to use a script that replaces all radios and selects with nicer looking representations...

In Firebug I can see the "replaced" radios have display none and checked="checked" is added or removed by the script.

Many thx,
Florian

Comment: are you creating the `radio` buttons dynamically.if yes you need to `delegate` the event

Comment: How is the script modifying the original input elements? Are you using a particular plug-in?

Comment: If you are programaticaly setting the radio butotn to be checked or unchecked, then fire the change event manually after doing that.. e.g. $(this).change();

Answer (score 0):

From the API:

"The change event is sent to an element when its **value** changes."

That means that the change event is not triggered if you only change the `checked` attribute. You have to change the value of the radio button that the `change` event is triggered.

Comment: how would you to that? is it change the value of the radiobutton or of the radiogroup?

Comment: I think, it is the value of the input tag with type "radio". You can just use $("#myradiobuttonid").val()